# How to access a field value in hook_preprocess_eck_entity

Tags: 8

How can I access a field value in hook_preprocess_entity(&$vars)?

I am able to do the following, but it does not seem like the best approach. What is a better approach?

```
function mymodule_preprocess_eck_entity(&$vars) {
  $myvalue = $vars['content']['field_myfield'][0]['#context']['value'];
}
```

Comment: Just noting that $vars['content'] in older code may be $vars['entity'] and should be updated to $vars['content'] to resolve this: "User deprecated function: You are using the 'entity' variable in your eck-entity template. You should use 'content' instead."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I can get the value with:

```
  $myvalue = $vars['eck_entity']->get('field_myfield')->getString();
```